# Django-ckeditor's content not being styled in html as they look in the admin page

Tags: html, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm using `django-ckeditor 5.8.0` with `python3.6`, `django 2.2.5` on `ubuntu 18.04.3`

`settings.py`

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        'width': '100%',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': [
                'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                'CodeSnippet',
            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage',
            'codesnippet',
        ]),
    }
}
```

`models`:

```py
content = RichTextUploadingField()
```

CKEditor's `static` files are served in `admin` mode but the `css` file(`contents.css`) doesn't load in other `views` elsewhere.

I'm using `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` and after running `collectstatic`, files exist where it should.

I've also added the following lines in the `template`:

```html
<script>window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "{% static '/ckeditor/ckeditor/' %}";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js' %}" data-ckeditor-basepath="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/' %}" id="ckeditor-init-script"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>

***

{{content|safe}}
```

Here's the image of the `html` from the browser :

[image]

Clicking on those two `js` files also shows its content, meaning they are accessible.

`contents.css` file isn't loaded, hence no styling.

Same story on the `development` `server` too.

Any suggestions to solve the issue would be great.

Comment: Where are your tags that you are expecting to load the CSS?

Comment: `django-ckeditor`'s `js` files are expected to load them dynamically I assume.

Comment: Are you getting a network error in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: No. That's what I'm unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try add this line to your content page.

```html
<link href="/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/contents.css" rel="stylesheet">
```